# Can someone help me write this in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write this code in javascript from jquery

I already tried but cant seems to get equivalent to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a').click(function() {

    var selected = $(this);
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(selected).addClass('active');
  });

  var $a = $('.a'),
    $b = $('.b'),
    $c = $('.c'),
    $d = $('.d'),
    $home = $('.home'),
    $about = $('.about');

  $a.click(function() {

    $home.fadeIn();
    $about.fadeOut();
  });

  $b.click(function() {

    $home.fadeOut();
    $about.fadeIn();
  });
});
```

The code works perfect in jQuery, but am trying to just use javascript. Its basically to add and remove class when a nav item is selected. I don't know if am explaining as clear as possible but am try to write the equivalent of this in javascript.

This is what I have tried.

var callback = function(){

```
 var clickHandler1 = function() { 

        document.getElementById("home").classList.remove("home"); 

       //var rem = document.getElementById("home");
       //fadeOut(rem);
       //alert("I am clicked B");
};

var anchors1 = document.getElementsByClassName("b");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors1.length; i++) {
        var current = anchors1[i];
        current.addEventListener('click', clickHandler1, false);
}

function fadeOut(el){
    el.style.opacity = 1;

    function fade() {
        if ((el.style.opacity -= .1) < 0) {
             el.style.display = "none";
        } else {
             requestAnimationFrame(fade);
          }
        })();
    };              

    fadeIn(el, display){
        el.style.opacity = 0;
        el.style.display = display || "block";

        (function fade() {
             var val = parseFloat(el.style.opacity);
             if (!((val += .1) > 1)) {
                 el.style.opacity = val;
                 requestAnimationFrame(fade);
             }
        })();
    };


 }

 if ( document.readyState === "complete" || (document.readyState !== "loading" && !document.documentElement.doScroll)) {

  callback();

} else {

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);

}
```

Comment: Use document.getElementById("elem").classList.remove("classnm");

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stack Overflow isn't a free code conversion service. The objective here is for you to show your attempts to solve your own issue and people help when that attempt isn't working as expected. Also the jQuery fade methods are not cut and dried since they require using interval timers to modify each step

Comment: Suggest you look into using css transitions for the fading

Answer (score 0):

The code in es6:

```
window.onload = function() {
  const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a')

  console.log(allLinks)

  const removeAllClass = () => {
    allLinks.forEach(link => {
      link.classList.remove('active')
    })
  }


  allLinks.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', event => {
      removeAllClass()
      element.classList.add('active')
    })
  })

  let $a = document.querySelectorAll('.a'),
  $b = document.querySelectorAll('.b'),
  $home = document.querySelector('.home'),
  $about = document.querySelector('.about');

  $a.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', event => {
      $about.classList.remove('fadeIn');
      $home.classList.add('fadeIn');      
    })
  })

  $b.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', event => {
      $home.classList.remove('fadeIn');
      $about.classList.add('fadeIn');
    })
  })

}
```

you can see working on https://codepen.io/rwladyka/pen/qBBBpvy

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementsByClassName('a') is the javascript equivalent of $('.a')

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question. Take a few minutes to read through [answer]

Comment: Not trying to *"act"* anything. Can see you are a new user and simply made  a comment that the answer does not fit normal SO standards and supplied a link with more details